# Intelij won't show sources for some kotlin classes

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I was playing around with Kotlin, when I stumbled upon some problems while looking through some documentation. I saw that some classes do not have source code attached. For example, there seems to be no source code/javadoc for the SetsKt.class, even though there is plenty for the other classes. Is there any specific reason for this?

Kind regards,
Jelmer[image]

Comment: Please check these issues: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10534
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25918.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quote from jetbrains issue:

> The reason for this behaviour is that facade class files (like
>   FilesKt.class) can be generated from several kotlin source files. So
>   when you click on such a file it's not entirely obvious what you want
>   to see. So we went with a conservative decision to show (admittedly
>   ugly) decompiled code for such files, which contain all the
>   declarations inside as opposed to showing some source file (which may
>   not contain the declaration you're looking for). We can improve the
>   behaviour so that when class file is generated from only one Kotlin
>   file it takes you to that file directly but this will not necessarily
>   help with more complex cases (such as kotlin-runtime) when single
>   class file is generated from several source files.